# How to start using MailKit library?

Tags: c#

I know that the easiest way to install MimeKit is via NuGet.

```
Install-Package MimeKit
```

Then `building`:

First, you'll need to clone MimeKit from my GitHub repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit.git
cd MimeKit
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After I did it I have +1 folder `MailKit` inside my project folder.
And when I opened my main project I expect that I can use

```
using MailKit; using MimeKit;
```

But I cannot do this. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install it and then rebuild the project.

Then you will see in the `Assemblies->Extensions` MimeKit reference

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build AND install from NuGet, just the NuGet installation is enough. After that, you add a reference to MimeKit / MailKit with the following steps:

> In Solution Explorer, select the project.
>
> On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
>
> The Add Reference dialog box opens.
>
> Select the tab indicating the type of component you want to reference.
>
> In the top pane, select the component you want to reference, and then
>   click the Select button. Press CTRL while clicking to select multiple
>   components. NoteNote:
>
> If the component you are looking for is not in the list, you may
>   locate it using the Browse button.
>
> Click OK when you have selected all the components you need.
>
> Selected references will appear under the References node of the
>   project.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

After that, you will be able to do:

```
using MailKit; using MimeKit;
```

Comment: Its strange but I can't find MimeKit / MailKit refference